# SublimeText3 и JS

Tags: javascript, html

Начал изучать JS по учебнику, и столкнулся с ошибкой при которой не отображается на странице JS код. Сначала скрипт писал вместе с html кодом, но потом решил разделить, но все равно ничего не происходит. Документ открываю через Chrome из разрешений в браузере включены только: Avast,ADblock и VPN.
JS код

```
    function main() {
document.write("<h2>Числа Фибоначи</h2>");
    for(i=0; j=1; k=0; fib=0; i<50; i++, fib=j+k, j=k, k=fib){
        document.write("Фибоначи ("+ i +")="+fib);
        document.write("<br>");
    }   
}
```

HTML код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Таблица факториалов</h2>
<script src="fibonachi.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас функция лишь объявлена, но не вызвана - нужно добавить в код вызов main().

Кроме того, у Вас синтаксические ошибки в условии цикла - надо так:

```
for(i=0, j=1, k=0, fib=0; i<50; i++, fib=j+k, j=k, k=fib)
```

Тогда заработает:

```js
function main() {
document.write("<h2>Числа Фибоначи</h2>");
    for(i=0, j=1, k=0, fib=0; i<50; i++, fib=j+k, j=k, k=fib){
        document.write("Фибоначи ("+ i +")="+fib);
        document.write("<br>");
    }   
}

main();
```